# Función que calcule la edad a partir de su fecha de nacimiento en PYTHON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

No se cual es mi error, podrían ayudarme?

---

```
from datetime import date
class Alumno:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, fnacimiento,direccion, telf, email):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.apellido=apellido
        self.fnacimiento=fnacimiento
        self.direccion=direccion
        self.telf=telf
        self.email=email

    def edad(self):
        hoy = date.today()
        fechanacimiento=self.fnacimiento
        edad = hoy.year - fechanacimiento.year - ((hoy.month, hoy.day) < (fechanacimiento.month, fechanacimiento.day))
        #primero restamos los años y luego restamos la comparación entre mes y día actual y mes y día de nacimiento. 
        print(edad)

alumno1 = Alumno("Raul", "Jimenez", "11/04/1996", "Calle la Paz 42", 920254565, "rauladd@gmail.com")

alumno1.edad()
```

Answer (score 4):

El principal problema está en que estás intentando hacer operaciones con fechas utilizando tipos completamente distintos. `self.fnacimiento` es una cadena `"11/04/1996"` y `hoy` es del tipo `datetime.date`.

Lo que se necesita es convertir `"11/04/1996"` en `datetime`. Para eso Python provee el método `datetime.strptime()`.

```
from datetime import datetime
fecha = datetime.strptime("11/04/1996", "%d/%m/%Y") # Tipo: datetime.datetime
```

El formato es el mismo que utilizado C (y otros muchos lenguajes). Las directivas usadas se pueden localizar en [este enlace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Con fechas con tipo `datetime` ya se puede restas fechas para calcular años, días, segundos o la magnitud que se desee, teniendo en cuenta que el tipo devuelto al realizar estas operaciones es `datetime.timedelta` Por ejemplo:

```
hoy = datetime.now()      # Tipo: datetime.datetime
diferencia = hoy - fecha  # Tipo resultante: datetime.timedelta
print("Años:", diferencia.days / 365)
```

Daría como salida:

```
Años: 22.81095890410959
```